# When to clear store (state) in a Redux application?

Tags: javascript, redux

Somewhere in the bowels of the Internet I've found someone stating, that normally you don't clear / remove anything from your store **unless** for performance reasons (storing large objects, memory usage I presume).

Is that true? Normally I'd think that on router navigation I clear data I loaded to render previous page. E.g.

1. Navigate to page A
2. Page A loads a document and store it in store (under "document" key)
3. Navigate to page B
4. Clear data loaded by page A (remove "document" from the store)
5. Page B loads some data on its own, stores in the store

Comment: Sounds about right to me, `/users/123` would load some data into `state.userInfo.details` and going to `/users/456` would replace that with different data, caching on the request service is up to you